# Getting more precision with GeoPandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, precision

### Geopandas

Reading a shapefile with GeoPandas and printing its total bounds:

```
dataframe = gpd.read_file('example.shp')
print(dataframe.total_bounds)
```

Prints: `[ 663590.5817 1541419.8307  724630.0589 1595869.4839]`

### PyQGIS

Doing the same with PyQGIS:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
layer = QgsVectorLayer('example.shp', 'layer1', 'ogr')
print(layer.extent())
```

Prints: `<QgsRectangle: 663590.58169999998062849 1541419.83070000074803829,
724630.05890000029467046 1595869.48389999940991402>`

---

As you can see doing it with PyQGIS gives you more precision than doing it with GeoPandas.

Is there any way to get the same precision with GeoPandas?

Comment: If you aren't mapping Higgs Boson detection in UTM, then it seems unlikely that a tenth millimeter is an appropriate precision much less tens of femtometers. You'd probably be better off rounding to meters. Obligatory XKCD reference: https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: Yes, definitely don't need that much precision, thanks for the links

Comment: What does `print(dataframe.total_bounds[0])` print?

Comment: It prints: 663590.5817

Comment: Next to not needing such high precision in most cases, it is probably also just a "representation" issue: pandas and numpy will by default only show the first decimals when printing them.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`geopandas.options.display_precision`** to specify how many decimal places to be visualized when printing the dataframe.

Note that internally the precision is not rounded, this is just a matter if displaying the coordinates.

Example, default behaviour:

```
>>> import geopandas
>>> world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
>>> world['centroid_column'].head()
0    POINT (163.85316 -17.31631)
1      POINT (34.75299 -6.25773)
2     POINT (-12.13783 24.29117)
3     POINT (-98.14238 61.46908)
4    POINT (-112.59944 45.70563)
Name: centroid_column, dtype: geometry
```

With 9 decimal places now:

```
>>> geopandas.options.display_precision = 9
>>>
>>> world['centroid_column'].head()
0    POINT (163.853164645 -17.316309426)
1      POINT (34.752989855 -6.257732429)
2     POINT (-12.137831112 24.291172960)
3     POINT (-98.142381372 61.469076145)
4    POINT (-112.599435912 45.705628002)
Name: centroid_column, dtype: geometry
```

---

Taken from geopandas [official documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/data_structures.html#display-options).

Answer (score 1):

Try using pandas (pd) settings:
*pd.set_option('max_colwidth', value)*

look here for more info:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html