# Why does the polygon saved in geodataframe have a different value from the shapely polygon it came from?

Tags: python, geopandas, jupyter-notebook, ipyleaflet

[image]

I'm working with Jupiter and ipywidgets and Ipyleaflet , trying to draw polygons on a map and saving to a geodataframe. I have the following in a notebook cell:

```
myDrawControl = DrawControl(
rectangle={'shapeOptions':{'color':rect_color}},
        polygon={'shapeOptions':{'color':poly_color}}) #,polyline=None)

def handle_draw(self, action, geo_json):
    handle_interaction("action ")
    handle_interaction(action)
    handle_interaction("geojson ")
    handle_interaction(geo_json)
    handle_interaction("geojson ")
    handle_interaction(geo_json['geometry']['coordinates'])
    global rects,polys
    global gdf2 

    coordinates = geo_json['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    polygon_coordinate_tuples = [(lon, lat) for lon, lat in coordinates]
    handle_interaction("tuples ")
    handle_interaction(polygon_coordinate_tuples)
 
    if geo_json['properties']['style']['color'] == '#00F':  # poly
        if action == 'created':
            handle_interaction(" created")
            polygon_geom = geometry.Polygon(polygon_coordinate_tuples)
    
            handle_interaction((polygon_geom))
            # Create GeoDataFrame if it doesn't exist
            if gdf2 is None:
                gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[polygon_geom])
            else:
                
                handle_interaction(" exists GDF2")
                gdf2 = gdf2.append({'geometry': polygon_geom}, ignore_index=True)
            
        elif action == 'deleted':
            polys.discard(polygon)
    if geo_json['properties']['style']['color'] == '#a52a2a':  # rect
        if action == 'created':
            rects.add(polygon)
        elif action == 'deleted':
            rects.discard(polygon)
myDrawControl.on_draw(handle_draw)
```

I printed out the coordinates when selected using the next cell:

```
action 
created
geojson 
{'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'style': {'stroke': True, 'color': '#00F', 'weight': 4, 'opacity': 0.5, 'fill': True, 'fillColor': None, 'fillOpacity': 0.2, 'clickable': True}}, 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[-88.433717, 31.659469], [-88.430242, 31.659505], [-88.430456, 31.657898], [-88.433331, 31.657679], [-88.434876, 31.658665], [-88.433717, 31.659469]]]}}
geojson 
[[[-88.433717, 31.659469], [-88.430242, 31.659505], [-88.430456, 31.657898], [-88.433331, 31.657679], [-88.434876, 31.658665], [-88.433717, 31.659469]]]
tuples 
[(-88.433717, 31.659469), (-88.430242, 31.659505), (-88.430456, 31.657898), (-88.433331, 31.657679), (-88.434876, 31.658665), (-88.433717, 31.659469)]
created
POLYGON ((-88.433717 31.659469, -88.430242 31.659505, -88.430456 31.657898, -88.433331 31.657679, -88.434876 31.658665, -88.433717 31.659469))
```

In the next cell, I run "print(gdf2)"  I get:

```
geometry
0  POLYGON ((-88.43372 31.65947, -88.43024 31.65950, -88.43046 31.65790, -88.43333 31.65768, -88.43488 31.65866, -88.43372 31.65947))
```

which does not appear to match the printed out coordinates in output.

Why not?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674/79 - for why the last decimal place doesn't really matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precision (number of decimal places) was rounded by geopandas for display when you printed `gdf2`. Internally, the precision has not been rounded and your geodataframe retains the full precision of the coordinates you created it with.

You can use `geopandas.options.display_precision = 6` to specify 6 decimal places are displayed when printing the geodataframe to match the geojson you printed.

See [GeoPandas display options](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/data_structures.html#display-options):

> `display_precision`: `None` [default: `None`]
>
> ```
>   The precision (maximum number of decimals) of the coordinates in the
>   WKT representation in the Series/DataFrame display. By default (None),
>   it tries to infer and use 3 decimals for projected coordinates and 5
>   decimals for geographic coordinates.
> ```

Related question:

- [Getting more precision with GeoPandas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424262/2856)

Example:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

geojson = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          1.23456789,
          0.987654321
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    }
}

print(geojson["geometry"]["coordinates"])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features([geojson])

print(gdf)

gpd.options.display_precision = 2 
print(gdf)

gpd.options.display_precision = 9
print(gdf)
```

Output:

```
[1.23456789, 0.987654321]
                  geometry
0  POINT (1.23457 0.98765)
            geometry
0  POINT (1.23 0.99)
                          geometry
0  POINT (1.234567890 0.987654321)
```